# PHP Cron Script No Longer Able to EXEC

Tags: php, nginx, centos, cron

So I have a cron script which runs a PHP script every minute.

It seems that the script is running, because it writes to a file, but the second part where it exec() a command does not seem to be working.

When I run the script manually the exec() works fine.

Any ideas to diagnose this? I have done some research, even changed the file permissions of the PHP script to 777 - no cigar.

The strange part is that my configuration had been working previously but has suddenly stopped working.

PHP info, as requested;

```
safe_mode   Off Off
safe_mode_exec_dir  no value    no value
safe_mode_gid   Off Off
safe_mode_include_dir   no value    no value
```

Comment: You catch the exec result?

Comment: I don't have the exec() output anything or write the output anywhere

Comment: Can you provide the command line you are trying to exec()?

Comment: exec("sudo service nginx restart");

Comment: have you tried to run cron script manually, in console, to see if they works?

Comment: I have not tried to run the cron script manually, but I know that the cron script is definitely running the PHP script because it does other stuff as well. It just isn't doing the exec()

Comment: So, you're trying to restart nginx, but it's it in use by PHP? I'm not sure that  will work. You may need to write a shell script and then cron somefile.sh.

Comment: Well it works when I run the PHP script manually, and it has worked in the past. Also PHP and Nginx are two different software, so it shouldn't have a problem

Comment: 1) `sudo` is necessary if you run cron under root? 2) try to change the command with absolute path

Comment: The crontab is already a full file path as follows sudo php /directory/another/thescript.php

Comment: @EddieChrisman I mean the `exec` script `/abs/path/to/service` (like `/sbin/service` depending of your sys conf)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite comprehend that last comment

Comment: i think he's saying to use the pull path to ngix; "/etc/init.d/nginx restart". See this post http://serverfault.com/questions/213185/how-to-restart-nginx

Comment: I changed the exec to that, and it still works when run manually but not via the cron

Comment: Alright, I tried something new. I wrote the output of the exec command to file and the output is Restarting nginx: nginx failed!

Comment: I don't get that output when I run the command normally myself though. Which is extremely extremely strange.

Answer (score 0):

Did the system administrator can something, such as "safe_mode"? What user is the cron running as? Are you sure that user has permissions?

Also, exec() may be risky. Be careful with all input!

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: The exec isn't dynamic, it's static so not much risk there. The cron is running under root, to be sure I can even do sudo phpscript.php and the exec() in the php script still won't work properly

Comment: Check phpinfo() to see if "safe_mode" is turned on.

Comment: Just added to OP, seems to be disabled